# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: pyinstaller python 3.8

Tags: python, pyinstaller, python-3.8

```
E:\programing\Python>pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached PyInstaller-3.6.tar.gz (3.5 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\users\никита\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\python.
exe' 'c:\users\никита\appdata\local\programs\python\python38-32\lib\site-package
s\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\
843E~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptitfmjcz'
         cwd: C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-vqw4tu5e\pyinstalle
r
    Complete output (36 lines):
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-jlh43b56\PyI
nstaller.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-jlh43b56\PyIn
staller.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-me
tadata-jlh43b56\PyInstaller.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metada
ta-jlh43b56\PyInstaller.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metada
ta-jlh43b56\PyInstaller.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-met
adata-jlh43b56\PyInstaller.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadat
a-jlh43b56\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadat
a-jlh43b56\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in positio
n 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\build'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\waf3-*'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\_sdks'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'bootloader\.vagrant'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'bootloader\.lock-waf*'

    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\source'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'doc\_build'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.tmp' found under directory
 'doc'
    warning: no files found matching 'news\_template.rst'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'news'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'old'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'tests\scripts'
    no previously-included directories found matching '.github'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.*'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*.yml'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '*~'
    warning: no previously-included files found matching '.directory'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadat
a-jlh43b56\PyInstaller.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Никита\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-jlh43b56\Py
Installer.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\users\никита\appdata\local\pr
ograms\python\python38-32\python.exe' 'c:\users\никита\appdata\local\programs\py
thon\python38-32\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_me
tadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\843E~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmptitfmjcz' Check th
e logs for full command output.
```

Comment: думаю проблема из-за того что имя пользователя написано кириллицей

Comment: А как можно переименовать?

Comment: переименовывать имя пользователя ничего не изменит

Comment: @Vadim.Sharoikin Хотя я уже давно пользуюсь pip с именем на кириллице и проблем с этим не было, но может мне просто повезло)

Comment: @Стас может просто у вас пользовательский "TEMP" и "TMP" через переменные окружения вынесены в другую папку

Comment: а что надо вписать в переменную чтобы она стала переменной окружения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй обновить pip до последней версии: python -m pip install ––upgrade pip
И если python ниже версии 3.8, то его тоже нужно обновить там эту ошибку пофиксили, и после обновления проблем быть не должно